# How to emulate boost::algorithm::find_if_backward with Range-v3?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, find, range-v3

I've been using extensively `boost::algorithm::find_if_backward` to get a forward iterator to the *last* element in a range satisfying a predicate.

How do I accomplish the same task using Range-v3?

This is my attempt, which looks a bit clunky; and I'm not even sure is robust enough. Actually, as suggested in a comment, the code *is* not robust enough, because when no element is found, `range_it_to_last_2` ends up being `std::next(v.begin(), -1)`, which is undefined behavior, I believe.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/find_backward.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/find_if.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/reverse.hpp>

using boost::algorithm::find_if_backward;
using ranges::find_if;
using ranges::views::reverse;

auto constexpr is_2 = boost::hana::partial(std::equal_to<>{}, 2);

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,2,2,3};

    // What I have been doing so far:
    auto boost_it_to_last_2 = find_if_backward(v, is_2);

    // The Range-v3 analogous I could come up with, but it's ugly:
    auto range_it_to_last_2 = std::next(find_if(v | reverse, is_2).base(), -1);

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it <= boost_it_to_last_2; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    } // prints 0 1 2 2 2
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it <= range_it_to_last_2; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    } // prints 0 1 2 2 2
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I would say you have problem for not found elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always know that a match is found, why not simplify to the following, getting the identical output:

**[Live On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zaY9bE)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/find_backward.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/find_if.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/subrange.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/reverse.hpp>

using boost::algorithm::find_if_backward;
using ranges::find_if;
using ranges::views::reverse;
using ranges::subrange;

auto constexpr pred = boost::hana::partial(std::equal_to<>{}, 2);

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {0,1,2,2,2,3};
    auto boost_match = find_if_backward(v, pred);
    auto range_match = find_if(v | reverse, pred).base();

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(boost_match), decltype(range_match)>);

    fmt::print("boost: {}\nrange: {}\n",
            subrange(v.begin(), boost_match+1),
            subrange(v.begin(), range_match));
}
```

Prints

```
boost: {0, 1, 2, 2, 2}
range: {0, 1, 2, 2, 2}
```

---

*(Some toy respellings for fun: https://godbolt.org/z/ccPKeo)*

Comment: Well, actually I cannot make this assumption. However, your example also shows that using an iterator _to the last_ element satisfying a predicate is probably a flaw, whereas using an iterator _to one past the last_ seems more appropriate. Your `subrange(v.begin(), range_match)` works well even if there's no match, because in that case `range_match` would end up being `== v.begin()` and the `subrange` would be empty. Thanks!

Comment: `find_if_backward` returns `v.end()` for not found, whereas range version would be ``v.begin` IIAC.